# Android App not launching, stopping unexpectedly

Tags: android

My android app won't seem to start. I made a few code changes in the main activity, tried to launch it and it crashed on launch. I then removed those code changes and it still won't launch. I can't find anything wrong with the code, here is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {


Button doSomething;
TabHost tabHost;
ViewFlipper flipper;
ListView listview;
ListView listview2;
HttpResponse re;
String json;
JSONObject j;
ListAdapter adapter2;



/*==================*/

ListView lazyList;
LazyAdapter lazyAdapter;
/*==================*/


private static final String LOG_TAG = "App";



@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    doSomething = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_something);
    doSomething.setOnClickListener(this);

    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.layout_tab_one);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);


    /*==================================*/

    lazyList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lazylistview);


   //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.fetch());
   adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.fetchList1());



   listview.setAdapter(adapter);
   listview2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    flipper.setOnClickListener(this);

    String tabname1 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab1);
    String tabname2 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab2);
    String tabname3 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab3);
    String tabname4 = getString(R.string.tabexample_tab4);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_one).setIndicator(tabname1));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_two).setIndicator(tabname2));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_three).setIndicator(tabname3));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setContent(R.id.layout_tab_four).setIndicator(tabname4));

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);




    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {



            Object item = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);






            SavePreferences("item",item.toString());
            MainActivity.this.refreshList();







             flipper.showNext();


        }});

    listview2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
             flipper.showPrevious();


        }});

    lazyList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
             flipper.showPrevious();


        }});








}





public ArrayList<String> fetch()
{
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        URL twitter = new URL(
                "JSON.php");
        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));




        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {







      //make sure youe String line is completely filled after that..
      if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("") && line.startsWith("[")) 
       {

      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
      Log.v(LOG_TAG,"jarray value: " + jArray);
      for (int i = 0;i < jArray.length(); i++) 
       {

         //SONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String country = jArray.getString(i);
          listItems.add(country); 
         // also make sure you get the value from the jsonObject using some key
         // like, jobj.getString("country");


        //istItems.add(jobj.getString(""));

       }
          }

        } 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}


public ArrayList<String> fetchList1()
{
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String selected = sharedPreferences.getString("item", "");



        URL twitter = new URL(
                "JSON2.php?item=" + selected);

        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));




        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {







      //make sure youe String line is completely filled after that..
      if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("") && line.startsWith("[")) 
       {

      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
     // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"jarray value: " + jArray);
      for (int i = 0;i < jArray.length(); i++) 
       {

         //SONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String country = jArray.getString(i);
          listItems.add(country); 
         // also make sure you get the value from the jsonObject using some key
         // like, jobj.getString("country");


        //istItems.add(jobj.getString(""));

       }
          }

        } 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}


public ArrayList<String> fetchImages()
{

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String selected = sharedPreferences.getString("item", "");



        URL twitter = new URL(
                "ImageJSON.php?item="+ selected);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"URL**:" + twitter.toString());
        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));




        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {







      //make sure youe String line is completely filled after that..
      if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("") && line.startsWith("[")) 
       {

      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
     // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"jarray value: " + jArray);
      for (int i = 0;i < jArray.length(); i++) 
       {

         //SONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String country = jArray.getString(i);
          listItems.add(country); 
         // also make sure you get the value from the jsonObject using some key
         // like, jobj.getString("country");


        //istItems.add(jobj.getString(""));

       }
          }

        } 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}


public ArrayList<String> fetchList2()
{

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String selected = sharedPreferences.getString("item", "");



        URL twitter = new URL(
                "JSON3.php?item="+ selected);

        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));




        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {







      //make sure youe String line is completely filled after that..
      if (!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("") && line.startsWith("[")) 
       {

      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
     // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"jarray value: " + jArray);
      for (int i = 0;i < jArray.length(); i++) 
       {

         //SONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String country = jArray.getString(i);
          listItems.add(country); 
         // also make sure you get the value from the jsonObject using some key
         // like, jobj.getString("country");


        //istItems.add(jobj.getString(""));

       }
          }

        } 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}







public void refreshList() {

    /*adapter2 = null;
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.fetchList1());
    listview2.setAdapter(adapter2);*/
    lazyAdapter = null;
     String[] imagesList = new String[this.fetchList1().size()];
        imagesList = this.fetchImages().toArray(imagesList);
       ArrayList<String> v = this.fetchList1(); 
       ArrayList<String> t = this.fetchList2();
        lazyAdapter=new LazyAdapter(this,imagesList,v,t);
        lazyList.setAdapter(lazyAdapter);
    //adapter2.notifyDatasetChanged();

}


   private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
       }





@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 public void onBackPressed() 
 {     
  flipper.showPrevious();

  }






}
```

Here's the manifest;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" package="com.myApp.android">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LazyAdapter" />
        <activity android:name=".ImageLoader" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Log Cat Output:

```
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myApp.android/com.myApp.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at com.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-28 11:16:32.442: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
```

Comment: which line is "MainActivity.java 84"?

Comment: doSomething.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you have a NullPointer. This line `doSomething = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_something);` returns null. Check if the Button id is really "btn_do_something" or if you have more than one same IDs assigned to different buttons

Comment: That did the trick, for some reason setContentView wasn´t called